# Maven dependency of persistence

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, import, dependencies, persistence

I use Maven, Tomcat Java EE and I want to add a dependency for this import :

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
```

I've tried these but they do not work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `but it does not work` ?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Error message ? or what ?

Comment: are you using eclipse? Maybe you have to update your project configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you use JPA 1 with Java EE 6? Java EE 6 already contains JPA 2 and this `javaee-api` artifact provides that classes. It can not work, whatever you mean exactly by not working here. Get rid of this JPA 1 dependency and try again.

Comment: i must use just this dependency :

Comment: i must use this dependency:<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Of course you have to use `javaee-api`, but you probably shouldn't use JPA 1 dependency concurrently.